# Show that the mean of a stable distribution exists

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, means

According [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution), the ch. f. of a $\alpha-$stable distributions is:

$$\varphi(t; \alpha, \beta, c, \mu) =  \exp \left ( i t \mu - |c t|^\alpha \left ( 1 - i \beta sgn(t) \Phi \right ) \right ) $$

where $sgn(t)$ is just the sign function and
$$ \Phi = \begin{cases}
\tan \left (\frac{\pi \alpha}{2} \right) & \alpha \neq 1 \\
- \frac{2}{\pi}\log|t| & \alpha = 1
\end{cases} $$

I would like to show

1. If $\alpha>1$, the mean exists and is equal to $\mu$;
2. Why the mean does not exist if $0<\alpha \leq 1$?

I could deduce the first moment by differentiating the characteristic function, but the sign function is not differentiable at zero.

Helps!

Comment: I find it very inelegant and impolite for someone to vote to close the question without leaving any criticisms or comments. It would be important for me to know what the problem is with my question. So I can improve it.

Comment: This would likely fall under the general theory of Levy processes. There should be an answer in some textbook (I'm writing this so that someone else can fill in the details : I don't have the time now). Bertoin's "Levy processes", Chapter $6$ which is completely dedicated to just stable processes, for example. Also see Chapter $3$ of Sato's book "Levy processes and infinitely divisible distributions", in particular Theorem $14.10$ which seems to contain some details.